# RMS stored values are not available after closing the Xlet Emulator

Tags: rms

I am running an LWUIT program on Xlet Emulator. I am storing data into RMS storage and could retreive it when the emulator is not closed but when the emulator is closed all the data in RMS storage is getting deleted I am running it on Eclipse IDE . Is there any way to store the data in RMS permanently so that i could retreive even after closing Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

No. Java sucks. You should know that.